# Mocha can't find my test files when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

My `test` script in `package.json` is:

```
"test": "yarn seed && (nyc mocha --opts ./test/mocha.unit.opts)",
```

My `mocha.unit.opts` is:

```
--require ts-node/register
--require source-map-support/register
--require ./test/unit/helper.ts
--recursive
./test/unit/**/*.spec.ts
--exit
```

My  folder structure looks like:
[image]

There's no error, however. It shows the coverage (all 100% somehow) and exits with:

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

When I run `yarn test`

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you run the mocha command directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you didn't give enough info about the problem. There could be few problems and solutions:

1. Check `package.json` (do you have everything installed properly)
2. Check `.spec.ts` files, can they compile properly
3. Can you try to run a test by test, maybe there is a problem in some of them
4. Try to run mocha directly through terminal without `mocha.units.opts`file